# How to change/block Laravel Monolog logging to 2 different locations

Tags: json, laravel, monolog

Laravel: How to change/block Monolog logging to 2 different locations

**This code creates a Monolog JSON Formatter**

LogServiceProvider->boot()

```php
$filename = __DIR__.'/../json_logger.log';

// // Create the logger
$logger = new \Monolog\Logger('json_logger');

$stream_handler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($filename);
$stream_handler->setFormatter( new \Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter() );

// Now add some handlers
$logger->pushHandler($stream_handler);
Log::pushHandler($stream_handler);

\Monolog\Registry::addLogger($logger);
```

Used like so

`Log::info('My json-logger is now ready', 'file'=>__FILE__,'line'=>__LINE__]);`

This will log to **json_logger.log** in *json format*

BUT will also log to **storage/logs/laravel.log** in *standard format*

I want to use JSON format exclusively in one location

Comment: Check docs for [Writing To Specific Channels](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging#writing-to-specific-channels). You could log to single channel with `Log::channel('json_logger')->info('My json-logger is now ready', 'file'=>__FILE__,'line'=>__LINE__]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new channel inside logging.php

```
'json' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/json.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
    'formatter' => JsonFormatter::class,
],
```

Change your .env if you want to use it as default channel.

```
LOG_CHANNEL=json
```

Or you can say

```
Log::channel('json')->debug('message');
```

Comment: I had to expand the formatter to 
**\Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter::class**
to avoid raising `not found` error

But it still created two entries

Answer (score 0):

**If** you have changed the `LOG_CHANNEL` channel to your chosen channel using `LOG_CHANNEL=json` and you are still logging to other channels you must also edit the default channel (`'stack'`) to use only your chosen channel.

**FROM**

```
    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single', 'daily'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],
    ...
```

**TO**

```
    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['json'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],
    ...
```